# MKLocalSearch how do I avoid results which have subtitle "Search Nearby"?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following this article: https://www.peteralt.com/blog/mapkit-location-search-with-swiftui/

And I've set up a LocationSearchService like this:

```
extension LocationSearchService: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        self.searchResults = completer.results
        self.status = completer.results.isEmpty ? .noResults : .result
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.status = .error(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

class LocationSearchService: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    enum LocationStatus: Equatable {
        case idle
        case noResults
        case isSearching
        case error(String)
        case result
    }

    @Published var queryFragment: String = ""
    @Published private(set) var status: LocationStatus = .idle
    @Published private(set) var searchResults: [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = []

    private var queryCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private let searchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter!

    init(searchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()) {
        self.searchCompleter = searchCompleter
        super.init()
        self.searchCompleter.delegate = self

        queryCancellable = $queryFragment
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(250), scheduler: RunLoop.main, options: nil)
            .sink(receiveValue: { fragment in
                self.status = .isSearching
                if !fragment.isEmpty {
                    self.searchCompleter.queryFragment = fragment
                } else {
                    self.status = .idle
                    self.searchResults = []
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get values like this with "Search Nearby" in them.  How do I filter this out?

[image]

Comment: I was able to find an answer below, but I used code very similar to yours. I noticed that there is a memory leak here. In the receiveValue I believe it should capture `[weak self]` and then `self.` should be replaced with `self?.`

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue.

I was able to fix it by specifying that I only want addresses and points of interest in the following way when setting up the MKLocalSearchCompleter.

```
searchCompleter.resultTypes = MKLocalSearchCompleter.ResultType([.address, .pointOfInterest])
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, this looks good for Swift, but I was working in ObjC. Also, we chose to implement autocomplete using Google Maps instead of MKLocalSearchCompleter for reasons unrelated to this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar issue. The MKLocalSearchCompleter class includes a property `resultTypes` which, according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleterresulttype), allows you to choose between:

- query
- pointOfInterest
- address

So it seems that you want to set the completer to exclude the result type "query," something like:

`completer.resultTypes = [.address, .pointOfInterest]` ** this isn't working code

I have found, however, no useful way to use this property. My solution has been to use a string filter to remove results include the string "Search Nearby":

```
- (void)completerDidUpdateResults:(MKLocalSearchCompleter *)completer {
    
    NSMutableArray *suggestions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray* results = completer.results;
    
    for (MKLocalSearchCompletion *place in results)
    {
        if ([@"Search Nearby" isEqualToString:place.subtitle]) {
            continue;
        }
        [suggestions addObject:place];
    }
    ... // do something with suggestions
}
```

or in Swift:

```
var suggestions : [MKLocalSearchCompletion] = []
for place in results {
    if place.subtitle == "Search Nearby" { continue }
    resultsToReturn.add(place)
}
```

I really dislike this solution, but it is working for me for now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it out to see for myself!  I ended up opting for Mapbox Search sdk, even though it is new and in beta.  Works, so unblocked :D

Comment: John, I think i figured this out.  See my answer.   Hope that helps.